# How to collaborate on a C project where not all are using Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm starting a C project where several contributors would like to use Visual Studio, and some would not. Is there a clean way to do this?

Visual Studio uses a .sln and maybe other files to keep the project organized, and to specify include directories and whatnot. And the non-visual studio contributors use the Makefile (I think).

Is there a way to synchronize these 2 things, so for example if a .c and .h file are added to the project by a non-Visual Studio dev it will be shown in Visual Studio? And likewise if an include directory is added in visual studio it will be reflected in the makefile?

Comment: I'd probably say no, without becoming insane, specially if the project is of significant size.

Comment: This sounds like madness; if a team can't agree on its tools, I doubt they'll agree on the code.

Comment: @SteveFriedl These are good old school days

Comment: What happens when they use language extensions? And what about VS's lack of compliance with C standards?

Comment: Are you aware of the tool "cmake"? It allows to abstract the build-control tool (make vs. Visual Studio projects). You describe the relation of code files and executables you want to build and cmake generates from that abstract description either a MSVS solution or a make file, both doing the same, selectable by the current user. It also allows to start either kind of build with the same commandline. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Visual Studio supports "makefile projects", but such projects are maintained via the makefile rather than through the project manager.  That's not really a problem - get the makfile advocates to maintain that!  Are you sure this is really a "collaboration"?  First step of collaboration - agree a common tools set!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-a-makefile-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: @WeatherVane : I'd assumed they were intending to use the MSVC build tools with a makefile rather than also using a _different compiler_ too!  At least the OP only mentioned VS "solutions" vs makefile.  A different toolchain altogether is a bigger problem.

Comment: @Clifford Right now I'm thinking we'll use a "solutionless" project in visual studio and simply compile using GCC and a script/makefile. Apparently most of the code completion and syntax checking features of Visual Studio will still work, and then the compilation will be identical between devs.